# Change just the year in a bunch of pictures?

Tags: macos, mac, camera, iphoto

So I didn't have the year set correctly in my camera and all my picture from a recent trip are ended up having a 2009 date instead of a 2010 date.

Is there anyway to batch change only the year for the picture and keep the time and month and day? In iphoto you can't just change the year by itself, and in mac os if you do select all, get information you can't really change the modifed / creation date ?

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a GUI tool that does the job. You drag the files to it and change the year of a bunch of files.  Here is the link in case anyone has a similar problem. [A better finder attributes](https://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderAttributes/)

I just noticed a second way of doing this. In picasa tools -> adjust date and time

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are. The meta info format is called [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format), and there is a command line tool called [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/) which can to exactly that.

Example invocations from the man page:

```
   exiftool -DateTimeOriginal-=’0:0:0 1:30:0’ dir
        Adjust original date/time of all images in directory "dir" by
        subtracting one hour and 30 minutes.  (This is equivalent to
        "-DateTimeOriginal-=1.5".  See Image::ExifTool::Shift.pl for
        details.)

   exiftool -createdate+=3 -modifydate+=3 a.jpg b.jpg
        Add 3 hours to the CreateDate and ModifyDate timestamps of two images.

   exiftool -AllDates+=1:30 -if ’$make eq "Canon"’ dir
        Shift the values of DateTimeOriginal, CreateDate and ModifyDate
        forward by 1 hour and 30 minutes for all Canon images in a directory.
        (The AllDates tag is provided as a shortcut for these
        three tags, allowing them to be accessed via a single tag.)
```

I am sure you can set the year to exactly 2010 in some way.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be to add 1 year to the date?

Comment: yeap the point was to add 1 to the year. This seems like a good tool I guess but to add the year do you have to add the equivalent in hours?

Comment: For adding 1 year, the `exiftool` command is: `exiftool -AllDates+='1:0:0 0' picture.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

My version of iPhoto has a menu item to change dates. It enables you to offset each file of a selection by a certain amount of time (i.e. some years, some months).